# Javascript check difference in days between dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two date variables that I'd like to compare the difference in days or hours:

```
var old_date    = 20160120030136;
var new_date    = 20160123190443;
```

My question is, how do I check using JS/jQuery the difference in days or hours between `new_date` and `old_date`?

Comment: Convert the 'dates' into normalized forms: proper Date representation objects or an epoch through linear time. Then proceed. I recommend `moment.js`, because it can trivially parse these into such suitable forms (and provides differences functions already).

Comment: Are those strings or numbers?

Comment: Why is there a down vote on my question? If there's something wrong with the question can the down voter  please let me know why. Thanks!

Comment: Those are strings but I can cover them to numbers if necessary.

Comment: Those 'dates' are number literals. If they are to be strings then the post is erroneous.

Comment: How do I convert the dates into normalized forms?

Comment: First, define the format of the date. Then convert it. I like `moment.js` because I am lazy, but one can also deconstruct the year, month .. time components separately. The endings - '30136', '90443' - don't appear to be time within a day, but rather perhaps a epoch from the start of the day. If so, that can be added to the day once you've created it from the other y/m/d components.

Comment: Okay so I used moment.js to convert my two time strings like this: moment(old_date).format('YYYY/M/D'); Now when I try and compare the two differences using var diffDays = new_date.diff(old_date, 'days'); I get 'new_date.diff is not a function' in console

Answer (score 1):

```js
function calc() {
  var old_date = parseDate(document.all['old_date'].value);
  var new_date = parseDate(document.all['new_date'].value);
  var diff = new_date-old_date;
  document.all['diff_days'].innerText = Math.ceil(diff/1000/60/60/24);
  document.all['diff_hours'].innerText = Math.ceil(diff/1000/60/60);
  document.all['diff_minutes'].innerText = Math.ceil(diff/1000/60);
}
function parseDate(dateString) {
  return new Date(dateString.substring(0,4),
                  dateString.substring(4,6),
                  dateString.substring(6,8),
                  dateString.substring(8,10),
                  dateString.substring(10,12),
                  dateString.substring(12,14));
}
```

```html
<div>Note: months are 0-based, so January is 0</div>
<label for="old_date">Old Date</label><input id="old_date" type="text" value="20160120030136"/>
<br/>
<label for="new_date">New Date</label><input id="new_date" type="text" value="20160123190443"/>
<br/>
<button onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
<div>Note: fractions are rounded up</div>
<div>New minus Old in days:<span id="diff_days"></span></div>
<div>New minus Old in hours:<span id="diff_hours"></span></div>
<div>New minus Old in minutes:<span id="diff_minutes"></span></div>
```